# Stored procedure suddenly hung - have the parameters sniffed?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2016 stored procedure performing aggregated weighted average on over 300 columns.

The procedure takes in `begin_month`, `end_month`, `monthly_flag` as input parameters.

The logic with the parameters is below:

```
create procedure sp_calc
     (@begin_month int, 
      @end_month int, 
      @monthly_flag char(1) 
as
begin 
    if monthly_flag = Y
       select begin_date,end_date 
       into _all_dates 
       where active_flag='Y' 
         and salemonth between @begin_month and @end_month
    else
       select begin_date,end_date 
       into _all_dates 
       where active_flag='Y' 
         and salemonth between @begin_month and @end_month 

    select a.*,b.begin_date,b.end_date
    into _agg_table
    from full_trans a, _all_dates b
    where a.sale_date between b.begin_date and b.end_date
      and a.sale_month = b.salemonth

    --begin aggregations
    select 
        col1, col2, col3, 
        sum(price * weights) / nullif(sum(weights), 0) as wp_price
    from 
        _agg_table
    group by 
        col1, col2, col3
end
```

This procedure takes about 2 mins to each for each month passed. `Full_Trans` table has around 500K records on a given month.

The other day I ran the procedure for 3 year period with `monthly_flag=Y` and it finished within 25 mins.

A few hours later, I changed the parameters and ran it for 201506, with `monthly_flag = 'N'`.

I was expecting the procedure to complete in its normal 2 mins time however it got stuck and ran for 2.5+ hours.

The `full_Trans` table is indexed and nothing else changed.

I rebooted the server, restarted DB services and tried - but no affect.

I tried with the `RECOMPILE` option:

```
Alter sp_calc <<Parameters>> 
    WITH RECOMPILE
```

but to no effect.

What could have happened here? Is this a case for parameter sniffing? IF so, how can I get back my normal times?

Any ideas? Any insight will greatly be appreciated.

EDIT: Thank you all for your responses. Rebuilding the indexes seem to have done the trick.

Comment: This can't be the actual SQL. Can you post the actual SQL? I say this because the very first line should throw an error and your selects are identical on both sides of the IF statement.

Comment: and can you give the execution plan?

Comment: *The full_Trans table is indexed and nothing else changed*... can you post the indexes, full query, and actual execution plan?

Comment: Also, I would want the indexes listed for _all_dates and _agg_table.

Comment: I would try updating the stats on all tables this is using.   Perhaps even reindexing indexes.  Even with stats on auto update they get out of line sometimes :)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged